# Sci-fi book about a family of space explorers who wake up from suspended animation, and land on a planet populated by lifeforms they call Churrs

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

This book is probably older, because it was few years ago that I read it, maybe around 2016 or so, and it was for a class that I read it. I cannot remember the title or many details about said book's cover, but I do remember that it had details of space on it, but this is a *very* vague memory.
But the story itself is what I remember the most. So, if any of this sounds familiar, I would much appreciate the help.

The story starts with a boy, a younger boy, who wakes from suspended animation with his family and a few other crew members. They left Earth many years ago and it has been too long to go back. They enter a star system which they name Emmett. They land on a planet, the name of which I cannot remember.

They land on the planet and start to colonize it. The kid's mother is a botanist and while discovering what grows well on the planet, she encounters a lifeform. (There are drawings/pictures in this book as well). The lifeform, which they call Churrs, has a wavy, hair-like appearance. It is a moldy green colour and can float above ground. And then some things happen and finally it is discovered that the Churrs, which make a humming sound when they move, actually have their own civilization and should be left well enough alone.

Those are all the details I remembered of this book. I am pretty sure the author was male, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 8):

This might be [*Journey to Openworld*](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Journey_to_Openworld.html?id=zJkDzIfTL2UC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (2001) by Wim Coleman and Pat Perrin.  It appears to be published (by Rigby Education) specifically for an education market, and the subtitle is "Leveled Reader Grade 5."

Google books provides the following blurb:

> Eleven-year-old Susannah and her mother are part of an exciting mission- the possible colonization of the far-off planet of Openworld. But for Susannah, the excitement is tempered by worry. Are there already creatures living on Openworld? And, if so, what will the coming of humans mean to them?

Susan's mother is a botanist.  They travelled in suspended animation:

> They had all spent most of the journey in a state of suspended animation, safely strapped into travel pods.

They name *something* Emmett:

> And a shy grin, Susannah said. "So let's call it Emmett."

Unfortunately I'm limited to the snippet view in Google Books, and it's hard to get any complete quotes.  But they definitely discover a race of hairy green creatures they call "Churrs."